# how to stop audio on android application

Tags: android, audio

I want to stop audio when pressing return or back button

```
public class buttonFour extends Activity{ 

    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button4);

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
        mp.start(); 
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
@Override 
public void onPause () {
    if (mp != null){
        mp.pause();
        mp.stop();   
    }   
    super.onPause(); 
}
```

but the music keep playing

Comment: @Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
  if (mp != null){
   
  
  mp.pause();  
  mp.stop();}
  super.onBackPressed();
}
}

Comment: could you plz update that on the question, that makes it easier to read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing another local `MediaPlayer` object `mp` inside `onCreate()`, thats why the instance variable never gets initialized, and never paused.

Just use the instance variable by replacing the line:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
```

with

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your MediaPlayer reference a global one.

Then override `onBackPressed()`

```
public class buttonFour extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button4);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
        mp.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
  if (mp != null)
    mp.stop();
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Edit, although the above should work, if it isn't you can try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause ()
{
  if (mp != null)
  {
    mp.pause();
    mp.stop();
  }
  super.onPause();
}
```

However this code will stop playback once the Activity goes off screen or upon a rotation change.

Comment: still not working. the audio keep playing when i press back button

Comment: try writing this: `if (mp != null) { mp.pause();
    mp.stop();}`

Comment: @Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
  if (mp != null){
   
  
  mp.pause();  
  mp.stop();}
  super.onBackPressed();
}
}

still not working

Comment: Are you pressing the back button when doing this? You could also try to override `onPause()` to see if it's working. See my updated answer.

Comment: yup..i press back button on the emulator button,  but still not working.. the music still playing

Comment: or if possible we can add the stop button on the screen?

Comment: You can, but the code to stop the media player should be the same.

Comment: then. what is your suggestion, just guide me

Comment: I suggest you take the local copy of mp out of on create

Comment: As my answer says, make mp global. Now you only need one reference. You needed to match my answer for it to work.

Comment: it works after i change this mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
        mp.start();

thanks bro

Comment: Good! Next time make sure to double check what you type in when you're testing someone's answer. You should also mark an answer as accepted now since your problem *is* solved.

Answer (score 0):

try to make `MediaPlayer` object global...
this works for me with the Global `MediaPlayer` object.

and then

```
mp.stop();
```